# Eigen3 : trying to allocate a cube matrix : execution failure

Tags: eigen3

I define a "`cube`" variable made of 4 nxm dynamic matrix.
Then I define a variable of "`cube`" type providing the nxm dimensions.
Compilation is ok but I get a crash @ exe.

May I ask you some hints please ?

Regards

Sylvain

Here is the code :

```
  typedef Matrix<Matrix<scomplex, Dynamic, Dynamic>, 4, 1> aCube;
  aCube myCube = aCube( 15, 12);
```

Here is the ouput :

> tstEigen: /usr/local/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:285:
>   void Eigen::PlainObjectBase::resize(Eigen::Index,
>   Eigen::Index) [with Derived =
>   Eigen::Matrix, -1, -1>, 4, 1>;
>   Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `(!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) ||
>   (rows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) ||
>   (cols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && (!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic &&
>   MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) &&
>   (!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) ||
>   (cols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && rows>=0 && cols>=0 && "Invalid sizes
>   when resizing a matrix or array."' failed.

Eventually, chtz put the bug in my ear. See below the working code :

```
  typedef Matrix<Matrix<scomplex, Dynamic, Dynamic>, Dynamic, 1> aCube;
  aCube myCube = aCube( 5);
  for ( int i = 0; i < myCube.rows(); i++)
  {
    myCube(i) = Matrix<scomplex, Dynamic, Dynamic>::Zero(4,2);
  }
```

Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: You can try `Matrix<Matrix<scomplex, 4, 1>, Dynamic, Dynamic>` instead, alternatively using `Array`. Or have a look at the unsupported Tensor module.

Comment: Many thanks, I've been misled by the C++ template syntax style. Many thanksfor your help chtz. I've modified my question with the final code I actually use.